# Best way of testing Repositories which use DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, dbcontext

In my projects, I follow repository pattern in order to easily unit test my ASP.NET MVC app. This allows me to easily mock the objects.

However, I am not testing the Repository logic by this way at all.

For instance, see the below blog post:

[How to Work With Generic Repositories on ASP.NET MVC and Unit Testing Them By Mocking](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-work-with-generic-repositories-on-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-them-by-mocking)

This is what I do and how I test my ASP.NET MVC App.

What do you think the best way of testing repositories which uses `DbContext` class to reach out the data?

- Directly getting data from database? (I think this would be the worst but I wonder your thopughts)
- Should I create a fake databse and fill it in with dummy data and point EF to connect that database?

And any other approach you might suggest.

**EDIT:**

I am using EF 4.2 here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The respository is you entry point to the database so the only way to test it is to use integration test and work on a test database. You can use transactional tests where each test will setup transaction and rollback at the end of the test to keep test data same for all tests.

Comment: I see. So, the only way is to clone the database structure, seed it with fake data and point EF to use that database on the test project. Did I get that right?